# GKPeerPickerController and GKSession

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, gamekit, gksession

we can connect by bluetooth only iPodtouch or iPhone using GKSession and GKPeerPickerController  right ? , or can we connect other bluetooth device ?

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth communication using `GameKit` (`GKPeerPickerController` and `GKSession`) is limited to iPhoneOS devices.

You can also use the internet instead of bluetooth, but once again, you are still limited to iPhoneOS devices.

If you are interested in using External Accessories, I suggest you check out [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/index.html) on the matter. Their documentation states that:

> Accessories can be physically connected to the device through the 30-pin dock connector or wirelessly using Bluetooth.

This still will not enable you to play games between devices that aren't iPhoneOS, as you need the iPhoneOS, and it's GameKit framework on both ends. If you are interested in setting such a thing up, you will have to look into managing it manually.

I would strongly advise *against* using bluetooth, as it's buggy, slow, and has a short range. Peer to peer Wifi or LAN play will be your best bets. I suggest looking into using Bonjour of you're using LAN play. Here are two tutorials ([one](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/), [two](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/10/22/mdns-and-caffeine-how-i-got-bonjour-running-on-my-iphone/)) on using Bonjour. Happy gaming!

Answer (score 0):

the last i heard, bluetooth is 'crippled' on the iphone meaning you can only transfer data via bluetooth to another device with an Apple approved bluetooth chip in it. check out the apple docs for developing 'accessories'.

Comment: You should get your hearing checked.

Comment: Sneakeyness - are you suggesting it's possible to connect the iphone to an arbitrary bluetooth device using the SDK? my understanding was the same as Remover's